# COMPRESS TABLESPACE 11g

Tags: oracle, compression

I have quite big datapump dump file and tried to load it into compressed tablespace that is created with "DEFAULT COMPRESS FOR OLTP" because of lack of free space. Anyway, when I look at "compressed" dba_segments and compare them with source segments they have the same size.
How does this compress feature work? I expected lower size of compressed tables but it seems doesn't work this way. P.S. Datapump job is not finished due to no free space left.

Answer (score 3):

The datapump export has the complete DDL for every object you exported.  So while the *default* for the tablespace is to compress, this can (and will) be overridden by any explicit setting for a table.

Check the COMPRESSION column on xxx_TABLES for the schema(s) you are importing to see if you are truly getting any compression.

You will need to use "transform=segment_attributes" variants on import to ensure that you strip off the storage elements of your objects to that they pick up the default you set at tablespace level.